# predict return different values from fitted.value

Tags: r, spatial-correlation

I am using `lagsarlm` in spdep package in `r` to estimate a spatial Durbin (mixed) model by

```
m1 <- lagsarlm(f, data = d, wlist, type = "mixed")
```

and using predict function

```
pred <- predict(m1,newdata = d, listw = wlist)
```

with the original data and spatial weight list to estimate the dependent variable. The estimation is different from the fitted.value in model.

From my understanding, the fitted.value in an Sarlm object is estimated with assumption that dependent variables are known. I wonder how does the `predict` function estimate a spatial mixed model with lag on both dependent and independent variables.

Comment: You have to provide more detail about your problem.